# Javascript code won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want this javascript code to push text into the `<td class='One'>`.
But for some reason it just doesn't work. Can anyone give me a hand here please?

```
<table>
  <td class="One"></td>
</table>


<script>
var freq =[2014,8,11];

    //Incidents & Injuries Frequency Rate
    window.tdOne = document.getElementsByClassName('One');
    tdOne.innerHTML = countUp(freq[0],freq[1],freq[2]);

</script>
```

Comment: Let me telepathically know what `countUp` does... a moment please.

Comment: Recommend reading this for advise on how to ask this kind of question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @torazaburo, while editing question you transform camelcase-ed classname One to one. TP, please fix it in question

Comment: I made no such edit.

Comment: No, it was "one" (in the `td`) in the original post.

Comment: there was not `td` in original post http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26886507/revisions . Anyway, thanks for adding it )

Comment: You can see the `td` in the original post f you view "source". Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns array of nodes ([array like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) for honest).

use

```
tdOne[0].innerHTML ...
```

This insert HTML only to the first find node. If you want to insert HTML to all found nodes use for loop or array map.

Comment: Are css class selectors case sensitive?

Comment: @PhilipPittle Yes they are, at the moment of my answer writing they were the same in question. It edition went wrong http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26886507/revisions